# How to make page(link) recognizable by social networks (vk) with Meteor?

Tags: meteor, share, social-networking

How can I manage web page on Meteor so that when I copy-paste a link to my blog page to any social network (especially VK.com), then it recognizes it as a page showing the link's title and description?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that to work the page has to be rendered on the server and returned as HTML to the social network.

Typically Meteor sites are only rendered on the client's browser. The only thing returned by the server is the Javascript application. This isn't just a problem for social networks, it's also an issue for SEO since search engines can't see your page.

If you're using Blaze then there's no solution that I'm aware of. You could try installing the spiderable package (which offers an ugly solution for index crawlers) however I doubt that social networks will use the required protocol which would cause the server to return the rendered HTML (the social network would have to retry the page load with `?_escaped_fragment_=` in the URL request)

However, if you're using Blaze the solution's much simpler. Using [FlowRouter SSR–(https://atmospherejs.com/kadira/flow-router-ssr) package the server will render your pages and return that to caller.